# How to get a segment between two points

Tags: mapbox, mapping, mapbox-gl-js, turf

I have a map made of two layers, the first is a list of trails (path) and the second is a point based layer (different intersection between the trails).

I am looking for a way to select a segment between two point without selecting the all trail, here is a screenshot of what I'm having now, the yellow line is when I click, i get the whole trail instead of getting only the segment between two points (white dots), what I'm trying to do is having only the segment between the two point , where I click.

I am using mapbox gl js and turf.js and vector tiles.
also if you can help me find a better way of getting the second layer (intersection between the trails)
[image]

here is the code I made so far:

```js
baseMap._map.on("click", "trails-data", (event) => {
  if (editMode) {
    var clickedFeature = baseMap._map.queryRenderedFeatures(event.point, {
      layers: [TrailLayerProperties.layerName],
    });
    var existingExtra = baseMap._map.queryRenderedFeatures(event.point,{
      layers: [SelectedLayerProperties.layerName],
    });

    if(existingExtra.length > 0){
      console.log(existingExtra);
      editComponent._selectedFeatures = editComponent._selectedFeatures.filter(
        (el) => el.id != existingExtra[0].id
      );

      baseMap._map
      .getSource(SelectedLayerProperties.sourceName)
      .setData(editComponent._clickedFeature);
      return;
    }

   
      let ark = [];
      let lines = [];
      editComponent._points.forEach((el) => {
        if (!turf.booleanDisjoint(clickedFeature[0], el.geometry)) {
          ark.push(el);
        }
      });
      console.log(ark);
      var ls = [];
      var feat;
      ark.forEach((it) => {
        var linesSplited = turf.lineSplit(clickedFeature[0], it);
        ls = [...ls,...linesSplited.features];
        console.log(ls);
      });
      let ptPt = turf.point(event.lngLat.toArray());
      if (ls.length > 0) {
        let min = ls[0];
        for (let i = 1; i < ls.length; i++) {
          let curMin = turf.pointToLineDistance(event.lngLat.toArray(),ls[i - 1]);
          console.log(curMin);
          let checMin = turf.pointToLineDistance(event.lngLat.toArray(),ls[i]);
         
          console.log(checMin);
          if (checMin < curMin) {
            min = ls[i];
          }
        }
        console.log(min);
        feat = min;
      }else{
        feat = clickedFeature[0];
      }
      feat.id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 * Date.now()); //random id generator
 
      editComponent._selectedFeatures.push(feat);
      editComponent._clickedFeature.features = editComponent._selectedFeatures;
      ark = [];
      lines = [];
      const length = turf.length(feat, { units: "miles" });
     
      baseMap._map
      .getSource(SelectedLayerProperties.sourceName)
      .setData(editComponent._clickedFeature);

  }
});
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add relevant existing code, otherwise question is most likely to be closed as not compliant with the GIS SE site policy.

Comment: @TomazicM done :)

Comment: This is a lot of code (so called wall of code), without any explanation of what main segments of code are trying to do and were particular you are stuck. Since I'm not familiar with Mapbox (only Leaflet & OpenLayers & Turf) and without possibility to test the code, I'm afraid I can't help you much.